# "Access is denied" when using mapped URL to Login.aspx

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to use web.config to map URLs to aliases.  All of them work just fine except for the Login page (Login.aspx).  This code works fine:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/Home" mappedUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
    <add url="~/Login" mappedUrl="~/Login.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

It routes me to the login page when I try to access the site, all is well.  But when I change the form login URL from loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" to loginUrl="~/Login", the site gives me a "Access is denied" error.

Anyone know why this is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to play with the access settings in the app.config

Comment: what version of asp.net?

Comment: why do you still use urlMappings when you have Routing in asp.net 4.0?